# AndroidStudio, ArrayList+SearchBar, how to get correct Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-intent

I am a beginner and I have a project to do for school. So the problem is, that whenever I try to open a new Activity on the Emulator by clicking on the listed entries I get to the activity, so far so good but the problem is because of the search bar, the positions of the entries changes. So as far as you can see in my code, Cyberpunk will always be the first entry and Dark Souls the second. But if I specificaly look for Dark Souls in the searchBar (it will only show up Dark Souls) I am getting Cyberpunk activity as a result since it is on position 1.

(I didn't finish all activities for the other entries yet, trying to fix this issure first)

I've already tried stuff like  if, switch etc. but I just get the same result. I would really appreciate any help! :)

Regards

Here is my Code:

```
package at.fh.joanneum.smartplay;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Searchlist extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchlist);


        final ArrayList<String> listGames = new ArrayList<>();
        listGames.add("Cyberpunk");
        listGames.add("Anno 1800");
        listGames.add("Dark Souls 3");
        listGames.add("Battlefield V");
        listGames.add("Minecraft");
        listGames.add("DayZ");
        listGames.add("Counter Strike");

        final ArrayList<Class> intents = new ArrayList<Class>();
        intents.add(Cyberpunk.class);
        intents.add(DarkSouls.class);


        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_activity_Searchlist);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listGames);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);


        SearchView mySearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
        mySearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String list) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(list);
                return false;
            }
        });

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Intent listIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            intents.get(position));
                    startActivity(listIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The top item is always the item at first index. Since you filter your adapter you change the order of items and therefore their positions, but you don't account for that when loading the Intent from your Intent List in the itemClick callback. You should either create a complex object that contains the display text and the Intent so when onClick is called, you can retrieve the clicked item and get the Intent from it. Or you can create a mapping of item-id and intent and then use the id-parameter of the click callback to retrieve the correct Intent. I would recommend the first solution.

Create a object like

```
class GameData{
  private String text;
  private Intent intent;

  public GameData(String text, Intent intent){
    this.text = text;
    this.intent = intent;
  }      

  public Intent getIntent(){
     return intent;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return text;
  }
}
```

and fill your ArrayAdapter with those objects instead of Strings. Once the item is clicked, retrieve the item for the clicked position from the adapter and call its getIntent() method. This will deliver the desired Intent.

Comment: Hello Basti, thank you for your help but I am still having some troubles figuring out how to implement the getIntent() Method, the problem is that I cant use the method .get(position) on an arraylist <GameData> because it requires me to handover an ArrayList<Class>